# Flutter, Firebase Auth How to access uid everywhere in the app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

it's my first app I try to code.

I am using Firebase Auth and Cloud Firestore in my app. How can I make the uid of the logged-in User available on every screen without using await?

I know I can get it that way:

```
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
String id = user.uid;
```

but I need to access the uid without awaiting it, for example here:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get groups {
    return Firestore.instance.collection("userGroups")
    .where("userId", isEqualTo: " uid ").snapshots();
}
```

As I am using the provider package I thought I can make it available through it. But how is the best way to do it?
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can `provide` the firebase auth stream above your app:

```dart
StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
  value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  lazy: false,
  child: YourApp(),
)
```

and when want to get the user you can:

```dart
final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);
```

Note, this will not listen to changes to the user object beyond signins and sign outs. To listen to actual user changes on the user (such as `isVerified` or `photoUrl` changes) you'll want to use a package like [firebase_user_stream](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_user_stream) and replace the previous stream with something like:

```dart
StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
  value: FirebaseUserReloader.onAuthStateChangedOrReloaded.asBroadcastStream(),
  lazy: false,
),
```